# How to test console.log output with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to test what console.log() printing. For example:

```
console.log("one %s three", two) ==> "one two three"
```

How can I get this final message ("one two three") using Jest?

P.s. It is important to check printing, not input parameters. Is it possible?

Comment: instead of testing what console.log prints.; test the variable "two"

Comment: Why you want to test console.log, why not just test the value ?
console.log is already well tested

Comment: @Code Maniac Someone could have console.log = function(str) {console.error("something else")}

Comment: I need to test output of winston's wrapper. I believe it will be same principal as console.log testing.

Answer (score 4):

You may not want to test `console.log` internal functionality (ensure that "one two three" gets printed) as that's not something you developed. The idea of unit tests is testing your own code and not external functionality, you just assume its gonna work as you would expect it to do. If it suddenly didn't do what you were expecting it's not like you are going to fix `console.log` inner code/functionality.

However what you could validate is that `console.log` gets called with the parameters you are expecting, which in this case you could achieve by spying on the `log` method:

```
const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

// I assume two is a variable? If not then don't forget to double quote like "two"
expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("one % three", two);
```

Comment: I made this simple sample because I want to test winston's wrapper which literally print some thing to console. Is there any way to test final printing or all what we can do is checking input parameters?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would still argue that it should be out of your scope to test that... but either way I think you can keep it simple and just check the inputs parameters. Can't think of an approach to store the output somewhere and validate it... Perhaps saving it into a file but I feel like that's a bit too over-engineered.

Sorry :(

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-console as I have in mocha testing, but it breaks on Jest cause it injects it self and prints other info such where it as called etc. But you can solve it easily https://github.com/jamesshore/test-console/issues/7

Comment: Well, ignore my above "solution". It can lead to problems doen the line. What we need is an option for jest to leave console alone! But the only option I see on Jest is 
`--silent Prevent tests from printing messages through the console.`